# Is there a less oddball way to generate this dummy data?

Tags: python, data-structures, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Input: a list of word_types e.g. ["verb", "adjective", "name", "noun]

Desired output:  a dictionary of three words for each letter-word_type combination arranged by word_type.

i.e.

{"verbs" : ["Averb1", "Averb2", "Averb3"], [Bverb1, ...], ..., "adjectives" : ["Aadjective1","Aadjectives2", "Aadjectives3"] ... etc

Here's what I used to generate my data.

```
import string
A_to_Z = list(string.ascii_uppercase)  #  list of letters a-z
lettered_word_types = ["verb", "adjective", "name", "noun"]

class Lexicon:
    def __init__(self, testing = True):
        if testing == True:
            for TYPE in lettered_word_types:
                setattr(self, TYPE + "s", [letter + TYPE for letter in A_to_Z])
        self.__dict__ = {key: [[element + "1", element + "2", element + "3"] for element in value] for key, value in self.__dict__.items()}


data = Lexicon().__dict__
```

Comment: To gain access to setattr which had the functionality I wanted to generate the final dictionary. I know it's incorrect to do this; I just cannot figure out the correct way.

Comment: You don't **need** `setattr`, you would just use `my_dict[TYPE + "s] = [letter + TYPE for letter in A_to_Z]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Note, everything you do in your for-loop is pointless, because then you *completely overwrite it* when you do `self.__dict__ = ...` is `L.__dict__.items()` supposed to be `self.__dict__.items()`? You really must provide a [mcve]. The code as written would throw a `NameError` for `L`.

Comment: Sorry about that I've updated the question, L was meant to be self. (i made a Lexicon object called L while I was writing it)

Comment: The for loop is to create an object with the attributes such that the line starting self.__dict__ has the correct attributes to make the desired dictionary

Comment: I believe your missing that I'd like to generate a list for each letter, for each word, not just a single instance of a word. That's what I'm interpreting from your my_dict[type + "s... comment

Comment: I think what you are missing is that `setattr(self, attr, value)` is **equivalent** to `self.__dict__[attr] = value`. Just see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class serves no purpose, it simply obfuscates what you are doing. To transliterate your code to use a `dict` directly, you just need:

```
result = {}
for TYPE in lettered_word_types:
    result[TYPE + 's'] = [letter + TYPE for letter in A_to_Z]
result = {key: [[element + "1", element + "2", element + "3"] for element in value] for key, value in result.items()}
```

So, just to show that this is indeed equivalent:

```
In [1]: import string
    ...: A_to_Z = list(string.ascii_uppercase)  #  list of letters a-z
    ...: lettered_word_types = ["verb", "adjective", "name", "noun"]
    ...:
    ...: class Lexicon:
    ...:     def __init__(self, testing = True):
    ...:         if testing == True:
    ...:             for TYPE in lettered_word_types:
    ...:                 setattr(self, TYPE + "s", [letter + TYPE for letter in A_to_Z])
    ...:         self.__dict__ = {key: [[element + "1", element + "2", element + "3"] for element in value] for key, value in self.__dict__.items()}
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: data = Lexicon().__dict__

In [2]: result = {}

In [3]: for TYPE in lettered_word_types:
    ...:     result[TYPE + 's'] = [letter + TYPE for letter in A_to_Z]
    ...:

In [4]: result = {key: [[element + "1", element + "2", element + "3"] for element in value] for key, value in result.items()}

In [5]: result == data
Out[5]: True
```